# Auto-Deskewing Images of Questions clicked from text books using Opencv/skimage in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I have followed a lot of Blogs, articles, tutorials on deskewing of Images but I am unable to deskew my image.

Here are some links to my test Images

1. [Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WKxc.png)
2. [Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ebIG.png)
3. [Sample 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfJOR.png)

I have used [4 points transformation](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/)

[Projection Profiling Method](https://towardsdatascience.com/pre-processing-in-ocr-fc231c6035a7)

[Edge Detection Perspective Transform](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/)

and lastly, [Text skew correction](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/)

and none of these worked on my data.

**I can not paste every code from each of the tutorials because it'll be un necessarily long**

Could someone please tell me how could I auto-deskew my images?

Comment: I do not think it is easy for those images. Images of only one line are not terribly good as there is no repeated pattern. Images that have curved text are not particularly good because there is not single angle. Generally, deskewing works best with multiply parallel lines of text.

Comment: So you mean to say that I'm deep in waters with no one to save me. Not even a single thing?

Comment: Correct, in my opinion